# imageviewtouch is not displayed in dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, imageview

I try to use the imageViewTouch utility on a dialog but the image is not displayed, changing from imageviewtouch to the common imageview the image is displayed correctly...

The imageViewTouch utility:
http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/
https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom

Here is the code for the dialog call:

```
    originalImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("DisplayImage", "onDoubleTap");
            DisplayOneImage doi=new DisplayOneImage(DisplayImage.this,"Original Image");
            doi.show();
            //                       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayOneImage.class);
            //                    startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here is the code for the dialogue to display the image:

```
public class DisplayOneImage extends Dialog implements
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    String itd;
    ImageViewTouch OneImage;
    String mypath = null;
    InputStream xsi1 = null;
    Bitmap xbitmap1;
    LinearLayout disp_img;

    public DisplayOneImage(Activity a, String imageToBeDisplayed) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = a;
        itd = imageToBeDisplayed;
        Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "2");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "1");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_one_image);

        OneImage = (ImageViewTouch) findViewById(R.id.photo);

        OneImage.setDisplayType(DisplayType.FIT_IF_BIGGER);
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "3");

        if (itd == "Original Image") mypath = "mydata.bmp";
        if (itd == "Image 1") mypath = "mydatazzz.bmp";
        Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "4");
            File xfile = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DSP2Android/" + "mydata.bmp");
        Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "5");
            if (xfile.exists()) {
                try {
                    xsi1 = new FileInputStream(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DSP2Android/" + "mydata.bmp");
                    Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "File is found");
                    Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "6");
                    xbitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(xsi1);


                    Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "Streamer created");
                    OneImage.setImageBitmap(xbitmap1, null, -1, -1);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("DisplayOneImage", "Fault");
                }


            } else {
                disp_img = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.img_original);
                disp_img.setVisibility(disp_img.GONE);
            }

    //        originalImage = (ImageViewTouch) findViewById(R.id.initial_photo);
    //       originalImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(si1));

    OneImage.setSingleTapListener(
            new OnImageViewTouchSingleTapListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSingleTapConfirmed() {
            Log.d("DisplayOneImage", "onSingleTapConfirmed");
        }
    }
    );

    OneImage.setDoubleTapListener(
            new OnImageViewTouchDoubleTapListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDoubleTap() {
            Log.d("DisplayOneImage", "onDoubleTap");
        }
    }
    );

    OneImage.setOnDrawableChangedListener(
            new OnDrawableChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDrawableChanged(Drawable drawable) {
            Log.i("DisplayOneImage", "onBitmapChanged: " + drawable);
        }
    }
    );

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Here is the xml for the dialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3E80B4"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<!--ImageView
    android:id="@+id/initial_photo"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/-->

<com.apps.gv.library.imagezoom.utils.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is some dubugging with logs that  I use as marks:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3b3e76f9 time:5306909
E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
D/DisplayImage: onDoubleTap
I/DisplayOneImage: 2
I/DisplayOneImage: 1
I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
I/DisplayOneImage: 3
I/DisplayOneImage: 4
I/DisplayOneImage: 5
I/DisplayOneImage: File is found
I/DisplayOneImage: 6
I/DisplayOneImage: Streamer created
D/DisplayImage: onDoubleTap
I/DisplayOneImage: 2
I/DisplayOneImage: 1
I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
I/DisplayOneImage: 3
I/DisplayOneImage: 4
I/DisplayOneImage: 5
I/DisplayOneImage: File is found
I/DisplayOneImage: 6
I/DisplayOneImage: Streamer created
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
D/DisplayImage: onDoubleTap
I/DisplayOneImage: 2
I/DisplayOneImage: 1
I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
I/DisplayOneImage: 3
I/DisplayOneImage: 4
I/DisplayOneImage: 5
I/DisplayOneImage: File is found
I/DisplayOneImage: 6
I/DisplayOneImage: Streamer created
```

Another thing that I do not understand is that even I tap the image only once in order to activate the dialog, there seems to bee multiple calls of the dialog...
(but I think it may not be the cause of the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this on your custom dialog class

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
```